# How to properly read and write .cfg files through python

Tags: python, config, configuration-files

I need help with reading and writing to `.cfg` files in Python. The `.cfg` files that I want to read and write have a specific format which cannot be changed.

An example `.cfg` file:

```
[META]
title = "Xxxx xxxx"
creator = "xxx"
artist = "xxxx"
artist = "xxx xxx"
title = "xxx xxx (xxxxxx)"
length = "4:59"
```

Some `.cfg` files can also have extremely long and formats (that I find weird). This is just a snippet of a very long `.cfg` file:

```
[EASY]
bpm = 100
offset = 0
spawn = [63, 111, 161, 201, 285, 339, 342, 347, 380, 388, 422, 449, 470, 507, 511, 531, 551, 555, 583, 591, 634, 638, 642, 701, 783]
half_spawn = [0, 1, 8, 16]
initial_data = {
    "type": 1,
    "animation": "xxxx.png",
    "looping": false,
    "fx": "",
    "background": [
        "xxxx.png",
        {
            "static": false
        }
    ],
    "voice_bank": {

    }
}
```

I've used libraries like *libconf* and *configparser* but none of these understand the file format and they report multiple errors.

The most luck I've had while trying to read this type of file is using something like this:

`lines = open('./test.cfg').read().splitlines()`

But even that results in multiple formatting issues and it's difficult to work with. I've seen other posts about this but they don't have quite the same format.

I'm not very experienced with Python, any help is appreciated.

Comment: which file are you trying to read, the top one or the bottom one ?

Comment: There isn't a single standard for config files. Knowing which program reads this .cfg could help come up with a solution. If its read by "foobar" you could do an internet search on "foobar config file format" or some such thing.

Comment: @D.L I want to read and write to both of them, but they are different files. The second one is in reality extremely big with tons of values but I tried keeping it short just to show the format that I needed to read.

Comment: This file format looks odd. I'm guessing that you may have to build your own parser for this type of file. I know that you mentioned that you can't change the format of your file, but if you want to avoid building your own parser, I think you would need to fully convert this to a more common format that supports complex nesting such as json or yaml.

Comment: @tdelaney The program that is going to read this is a rythm game which to my knowledge has been made in a game engine called godot which I belive is based on C.

Comment: @frenchytheasian This dose sound like something I might have to end up doing although I have no idea how. Since I have no possibility of altering the format of the .cfg since a program that I cant edit has to read it. I am simply modding a game.

Comment: Godot [ConfigFile](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_configfile.html) looks like what you've got. Link shows GDScript and CSharp accessors. Not sure how that helps except maybe the game would accept GDScripts you could use. Maybe a separate CSharp program that converts to something python can parse. Have it write to stdout.

Comment: @tdelaney I'm not sure what you mean by stdout but thanks a lot, you've put me on the right track for figuring this out. I will look into making a sperate c# program that either dose everything I want for me completely dumping python or I will integrate c# together with my current python program.

Comment: My thought was a C# program that takes a config file, creates a JSON and writes it to sys.stdout. Then with a `subprocess.run` call in python, you could get the JSON without touching the hard drive with a temporary file. After a bit of searching, it seems like others have also worked the json angle. There may already be a tool out there.

Comment: @tdelaney This will definitely be a challenge for me but I'm up for it. I will try to do as you said and also look for a tool that might already do what I want with the json part.

Comment: This actually isn't impossible to do with just the standard library tools, just a second...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a small state machine to support the "complex" multi-line values, and the standard library's `ast.literal_eval()` and `json.loads()` to turn the values to Python data.

This will fail for invocations such as `Vector3(0, 0, 0)` which are valid in Godot files, but you can pretty easily add code to e.g. skip those, or use e.g. the `pure-eval` library to deal with them.

Assuming the `data_fp` variable is an open file (I used an `io.StringIO()` for testing),

```
import ast
import io
import json
import sys

def parse_godot_value(value: str):
    # The Godot complex value seems to be pretty much just JSON.
    return json.loads(value)


def parse_godotesque_ini(fp):
    current_section = None
    complex_key = None
    complex_value = None
    for line in fp:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if not line:
            continue
        if line.startswith("["):
            current_section = line.strip("[]")
            continue
        if complex_value is None:  # Not busy parsing a complex value
            key, _, value = line.partition("=")
            key = key.strip()
            value = value.strip()
            if not (key and value):
                continue
            if value == "{":
                complex_key = key
                complex_value = ["{"]  # Start of a complex value
            else:
                yield (current_section, key, parse_godot_value(value))
        else:  # Busy parsing a complex value
            complex_value.append(line)
            if line == "}":  # End of a complex value
                yield (current_section, complex_key, parse_godot_value("\n".join(complex_value)))
                complex_key = None
                complex_value = None


for section, key, value in parse_godotesque_ini(data_fp):
    print(section, key, value)
```

prints out

```
META title Xxxx xxxx
META creator xxx
META artist xxxx
META artist xxx xxx
META title xxx xxx (xxxxxx)
META length 4:59
EASY bpm 100
EASY offset 0
EASY spawn [63, 111, 161, 201, 285, 339, 342, 347, 380, 388, 422, 449, 470, 507, 511, 531, 551, 555, 583, 591, 634, 638, 642, 701, 783]
EASY half_spawn [0, 1, 8, 16]
EASY initial_data {'type': 1, 'animation': 'xxxx.png', 'looping': False, 'fx': '', 'background': ['xxxx.png', {'static': False}], 'voice_bank': {}}
```

for the data you pasted.

Good luck!

---

EDIT:

For emitting a similar format,

```
def write_godotesque_ini(fp, data_dict):
    for section, items in data_dict.items():
        fp.write(f"[{section}]\n")
        for key, value in items.items():
            indent = 4 if isinstance(value, dict) else None
            fp.write(f"{key} = {json.dumps(value, indent=indent)}\n")
        fp.write("\n")


new_data = {
    "META": {
        "title": "Xxxx xxxx",
        "creator": "xxx",
    },
    "EASY": {
        "half_spawn": [0, 1, 8, 16],
        "initial_data": {
            "type": 1,
            "animation": "xxxx.png",
        },
    },
}

write_godotesque_ini(sys.stdout, new_data)
```

writes

```
[META]
title = "Xxxx xxxx"
creator = "xxx"

[EASY]
half_spawn = [0, 1, 8, 16]
initial_data = {
    "type": 1,
    "animation": "xxxx.png"
}
```

to standard output.

Comment: Thanks a lot this works very well for reading the files, do you have any idea how I could write to a similar looking Godot .cfg file?

Comment: Given the format is (as we saw) pretty close to just Python `repr`s, you should be able to just pretty much write lines of style `f"{key} = {value!r}"`...

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean and it dosent feel like this will let me write different new values to a new .cfg file. Cause at the end what I want to do is read some values and re write them in a similar format to a completely new .cfg file thanks for helping. (Writing is the only issue for me now)

Answer (score -1):

**One possible solution could be to use the python-libconf library, which is a pure-Python**

this is an example of use:

```
import libconf
with io.open('file.cfg', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    cfg = libconf.load(f)
```

Comment: I have tried this before and libconf is not able to load the file. Just gets multiple errors.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).